# How do I fix this game loop function problem

Tags: python

my problem is that when i run my code it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\crossy rpg game\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    game.run_game_loop()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'run_game_loop'
PS C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\crossy rpg game>
```

how do i fix this

CODE==

so there are 2 subjects 1 is for organizing 1 is for function
code from the organization # game.py:import pygame

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):

        self.width = 1850
        self.height = 1000
        self.white_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.red_color = (255,0,0)
        self.green_color = (0,255,0)
        self.blue_color = (0,0,255)
        self.game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width,self.height))


        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()


        background_image = pygame.image.load('assets/background.png')
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (self.width,self.height))

        tresure_image = pygame.image.load('assets/tresure.jpg')
        self.tresure_image = pygame.transform.scale(tresure_image, (100,100))  

def draw_objects(self):
    self.game_window.fill(self.white_color)


    self.game_window.blit(self.background, (0,0))
    self.game_window.blit(self.tresure_image, (900,50))
            
    pygame.display.update()
        
        
def run_game_loop(self):
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
    
    
        self.draw_objects()
    


        self.clock.tick(60)
```

so there are 2 subjects 1 is for organizing 1 is for function
code from the function #main.py:import pygame
from game import Game

pygame.init()

game = Game()
game.run_game_loop()

pygame.quit()
quit()

I've tried swapping the veribles and stuff but it just did nothing or made it worse

Comment: The way you have defined `run_game_loop()`, it is a separate standalone function; it is NOT indented to be part of the `Game` class.

Comment: So how do I make it part of game? I really need to get this done before I’m driven insane. It is 12:05 for me and I need to get up at 7 so yea I need help

Comment: indentation. you need to indent the method

Comment: Sorry, I’m new, I seriously just started and I made most of this off a vid so uhh what do I need to indent

Comment: Indentation is critical to the intention of your code. Try this: [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that the functions `draw_objects` and `run_game_loop` are not correctly indented, leading the python interpreter to believe that they are not a part of the `Game` class.

For example, in the below code, (taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html))

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)

    def addtwice(self, x):
        self.add(x)
        self.add(x)
```

we have correctly indented the `add` and `addtwice` methods. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for more information on indentation in Python.

So the solution to your problem would be to correctly indent the functions `draw_objects` and `run_game_loop`.

Edit:

I'll just give you part of the solution here, as my answer seems to be a bit confusing,

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):

        self.width = 1850
        self.height = 1000
        self.white_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.red_color = (255,0,0)
        self.green_color = (0,255,0)
        self.blue_color = (0,0,255)
        self.game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width,self.height))


        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()


        background_image = pygame.image.load('assets/background.png')
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (self.width,self.height))

        tresure_image = pygame.image.load('assets/tresure.jpg')
        self.tresure_image = pygame.transform.scale(tresure_image, (100,100))  

    def draw_objects(self):
        self.game_window.fill(self.white_color)


        self.game_window.blit(self.background, (0,0))
        self.game_window.blit(self.tresure_image, (900,50))
            
        pygame.display.update()
        
        
def run_game_loop(self):
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
    
    
        self.draw_objects()
    


        self.clock.tick(60)
```

Notice how the `draw_objects` function now has 4 spaces added to each line? That indentation tells the Python interpreter that this function is actually a method belonging to the `Game` class. By doing the same with the `run_game_loop` function, your problem should be fixed. I encourage you to try the same and rerun your code.

Comment: it still says:PS C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\crossy rpg game> & C:/Users/james/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.12.exe "c:/Users/james/OneDrive/Desktop/crossy rpg game/main.py"
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.12.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\crossy rpg game\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    game.run_game_loop()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'run_game_loop'
PS C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\crossy rpg game>

Comment: @Phix I wanted the OP to at least try to attempt a solution by themselves...

Comment: That's fair, just confused to the approach.

Comment: @Phix Understandable, I've edited the question to add an example using their own code.